# stristr not working with html tags

Tags: php, html, string, dom, html-parsing

I am creating a RSS feed aggregator which retrieves not just the description but also the entire content of the post by visiting each links.I am filtering unwanted info like facebook,twitter followers and other content from the post using stristr.It works perfect for one feed and doesn't work with other.This is my code:

```
<?php
function getcontent($l,$b,$c)
{
    $dom=file_get_html($l);
    $atitle=$dom->find($b);
    $content=$dom->find($c);
    $contents=implode(" ",$content);
foreach($atitle as $t)
            {
                echo "<b>".$t."</b>";

            }
            echo "<br /><br />";
        echo $contents;
        echo "<br />";
}
function filtercontent($strip,$l,$b,$c)
{
    $dom=file_get_html($l);
    $atitle=$dom->find($b);
    $content=$dom->find($c);
    $contents=implode(" ",$content);
    $contents=stristr($contents,$strip,true);
    foreach($atitle as $t)
            {
                echo "<b>".$t."</b>";

            }
            echo "<br />";
            echo $contents;
            echo "<br /><br />";

}
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
ini_set('max_execution_time',0);
ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
include("simple_html_dom.php");

$url=array("http://www.deccanherald.com/rss/news.rss","http://syndication.indianexpress.com/rss/798/latest-news.xml");

$atitle=NULL;
$content=NULL;
foreach($url as $feed)
{
    $f=$feed;
    $feed=simplexml_load_file($feed);
    //echo $feed;
    if($feed)
    {
        //$feed_title=$feed->channel->title;
        //echo "<br />".$feed_title."<br />";
        $items=$feed->channel->item;
        foreach($items as $item)
        {
            //foreach($keywords as $key)
            //{
            //if(strtolower($item->description)==$key || strtolower($item->title)==$key)
            //{

        $title=$item->title;
        //echo "<h1><b>".$title."</b></h1><br />";
        $link=$item->link;
        //echo "<a href='".$link."'>".$link."</a><br />";
        $des=$item->description;
        //echo "<br />".$des."<br />";


            if($f=="http://beta.thehindu.com/news/?service=rss")
            {
            $title_class=".detail-title";
            $content_class=".body";
            getcontent($link,$title_class,$content_class);

            }
            if($f=="http://in.news.yahoo.com/rss/national/")
            {
            $title_class=".headline";
            $content_class=".yom-art-content";
            getcontent($link,$title_class,$content_class);
            }


        if($f=="http://syndication.indianexpress.com/rss/798/latest-news.xml")
            {

            $link=$link."0";
            $title_class=".headstory";
            $content_class=".contentLeftbigstory";
            $strip='<div class="paginationNew">';
            filtercontent($strip,$link,$title_class,$content_class);

            }
            if($f=="http://www.indiatvnews.com/rssfeed/india_news.xml")
            {

            $title_class=".topstorytitsub";
            $content_class=".standard";
            foreach($link as $post)
            {
                $dom=file_get_html($link);
                $title=$dom->find($title_class);
                $content=$dom->find('div[style=min-height:350px]');
                foreach($title as $t)
                echo "<b>".$t."</b><br />";
                foreach($content as $c)
                {
                    echo $c;

                }

            }


            }
            if($f=="http://beta.thehindu.com/news/?service=rss")
            {
            $title_class=".detail-title";
            $content_class=".body";
            getcontent($link,$title_class,$content_class);

            }
            if($f=="http://www.deccanherald.com/rss/news.rss")
            {
            $title_class=".newsText";
            $content_class=".postedBy";
            $strip='<a href="#top" class="gototop">Go to Top</a>';
            filtercontent($strip,$link,$title_class,$content_class);            
            }


            }
    }
        }


?>
```

I use [simple html dom parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) to parse the html.The filtercontent function takes a piece of string as input apart from other inputs.This string called strip is used to filter and return all the contents before the first occurence of strip string.It works perfect with the syndication.com feed but fails with the deccanherald.com feed.I have excluded other feeds for easy understanding and also others use getcontent function which works fine.The sample-source of a post in deccan herald is:

```
<h1>Crazy star Ravichandran takes potshots at TV channels</h1>

                                                            <div class="postedBy">Mysore, September 28, 2012, DHNS:
                                                                                            <p>Actor opens ‘Conflux 2012’ media fest at Mahajana’s college in city</p>
                                                        <a name="top"></a>

                                                        <p><p><strong>When actor, director and producer of Kannada filmdom V&#8200;Ravichandran was invited to inaugurate &lsquo;Conflux 2012&rsquo; a two-day inter-collegiate media and communication fest of&#8200;SBRR&#8200;Mahajana First&#8200;Grade College in the city on Friday, many would have thought it contrasting.</strong><br /><br />However, when Ravi as he is popular among his acolytes, took over the dais and addressed the gathering where youngsters topped others, the choice of selecting Ravichandran to open the fest seemed apt. <br /><br />Mincing no words, the actor nick named &lsquo;Crazy Star&rsquo; made a relevant remark taking potshots at the electronic media for opting negativism rather than positive aspects to up their television rating points (TRP). Taking the names of two channels in Kannada, the actor said they are indulging in taking the people for a ride with concocted facts.<br /><br /> More than that, almost all the channels are airing moribund programmes. Said&#8200;Ravichandran; &ldquo; Pen is mightier than sword and show your talent in reaching the people and guide them.&rdquo;<br /><br />On filmdom, Ravichandran said that the fans still want him to romance heroines like what he did in Premaloka and other flicks. &ldquo;&#8200;I have already turned 50&rdquo;, said&#8200;Ravichandran making it clear that he cannot redo what he did in the past.&#8200;Referring to &lsquo;Manjina Hani&rsquo; the most awaited movie from his banner from the past several years, the actor said &lsquo;he is discovering the man in him&rsquo;.  <br /><br />Earlier, it was a filmy welcome to the actor. No sooner he entered the hall, pat filled the air an all time hit song from Ranadheera; baa baaro ranadheera...  <br /><br />Principal of the college&#8200;Prof K&#8200;V&#8200;Prabhakar said students from as many as 18 colleges from several parts of the State are participating in the fest.</p><p>To avoid chaos, the management had prohibited the entry of outsiders (especially students). <br /><br />Barring the participants, dignitaries and media, others were not allowed with students of the college keeping a tab on the visitors at the main gate of Vivekananda Hall of the college.<br /><br />Jayalakshmipuram police had to disperse the mad crowd who had dared to assemble in front of the hall.<br /><br />Chairman of&#8200;Mahajana Education Society R&#8200;Vasudevamurthy, HoD, mass communication and journalism Nivedita and others were present.<br /><br /><strong>Supports Cauvery stir</strong><br /><br />Actor&#8200;Ravichandran on&#8200;Friday extended support to ongoing agitation against the centre&rsquo;s directive to State to release 9,000 cusec of water to Tamil Nadu. On Karnataka bandh call given by various organisations on October 6 over the same issue, the actor said he too will support following Karnataka&#8200;Film&#8200;Chamber of Commerce&rsquo;s (KFCC) similar announcement. &ldquo;When the State itself is facing acute water shortage, how can we release water to them&rdquo;, the actor asserted. He also denied any interests to join politics saying; nange rajakeeya barolla (I don&rsquo;t know politics).</p></p>

                            <p class="gotoTop"><a href="#top" class="gototop">Go to Top</a></p>


                            <div class="socialNetworkingLinks">
                                 <a href="http://www.deccanherald.com/tell_a_friend.php?id=281782" style="margin-left:-5px;"><img src="http://www.deccanherald.com/images/email.jpg" alt="" border="0" /></a> 
                                <a href="#" onClick="javascript:window.print();"><img src="http://www.deccanherald.com/images/print.jpg" alt="" border="0" onClick="javascript:window.print();" /></a> 
                                <a href="javascript:addToFavorites()"><img src="http://www.deccanherald.com/images/bookmark.jpg" alt="" border="0" /></a>
```

I also used `$strip='<p class="gotoTop">'` and also `$strip='<div class="socialNetworkingLinks">'` and `$strip="Go to Top"` but nothing works everything return results with the get to top and socialize toolbar.Why it doesn't work. What's wrong with my code.It's working for one feed but not the other.Please help me fix this.

Screenshot:
[image]

I want to remove contents starting from "Go to Top".

Comment: That's a lot of code, can't you give an example of input and the resulting output that fails with your function?

Comment: @jeroen:Ok I will add a screenshot.

Comment: Didn't help a lot, the screenshot. Please, just post the part of code that causes the problem, the output (eventually error message), and the desired output/result.

Comment: @Havelock: Just look at filtercontent function and the if loop with $f=="http://deccanherald.com....." .I have also updated my screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with `$content_class=".postedBy";`. The only thing in that class is `Mysore, September 28, 2012, DHNS:`, which doesn't match `$strip`.

EDIT:

The postedBy DIV looks like:

```
<div class="postedBy">Mysore, September 28, 2012, DHNS:</div>
```

It doesn't include the body of the article.

Comment: Sorry you are wrong.The div .postedBy doesn't close.So it extends till the entire post and also I get the output properly using that.The only problem is cutting the undesired content.Anyways thanks for the reply.

Comment: Are you kidding?Why did you add the </div>.It's not there in the source.

Comment: I just cut and pasted from your question. I didn't add anything, I promise. Please someone else tell me I'm not imagining it.

Comment: Scroll right in the textarea containing the pasted web page, you'll see the `</div>`.

Comment: Sorry It was added by me by mistake.The close tag was not there in the original post.

Comment: Thank You for your suggestion.I fixed it using a new feed class.